# JOIN in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax-error, inner-join

MYSQL is returning error **Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "=" at [9:66]**
in result if below INNER JOIN Query:

```
SELECT
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.Employees`.name,
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.Employees`,role,
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.departments`.department_id
FROM
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.Employees`
INNER JOIN
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.departments` ON
`spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.departments`,department_id = `spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.Employees`.department_id
```

Can someone please help to understand what is the error?

I have tried writing the query differently many times but it dosent work.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: *MYSQL is returning error **Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "=" at [9:66]*** ?? This is NOT MySQL error message. It looks like BigQuery error mesage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two typos, one in the select, one in the ON statement, where you used a `,` instead of a `.`. Also consider using aliases for the tables for readability.

```
SELECT
  EMP.name,
  EMP.role,
  DEP.department_id
FROM `spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.Employees` AS EMP
JOIN `spherical-realm-388112.Customer_Data.departments` AS DEP
  ON EMP.department_id = DEP.department_id
```

Comment: Great Thank you. I just came across Aliases in SQL. will use them going forward.